# Problem on suggestion with Jquery AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, autocomplete, unique

I encounter the problem and I can't solve it.

So on a forum, I wanted to create a script that allows you to select a sticker in a suggestion box when you type a keyword :stick for example.

But the problem is that the script always detects the ":" and so when I type the other words, it still displays the suggestion, I put the link here : https://jsfiddle.net/z4v689fj/10/ with the complete code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){



$("head link[rel='stylesheet']").last().after("<link rel='stylesheet' href='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>");

    var jsonRisitas = 
[{"label":" :risitas :pixel :risi :reso :reso","value":"http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/19/1494259658-pixistas2.png"},{"label":" :risitas :possedo :risi :issou :deforme :yeux :possede :demon :defonce :jpp :zoom :clown :cirque :circus :circus","value":"http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/22/2/1559078100-1558768973-risitas-possedo-clown.png"}];
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( / \s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#message_topic" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
        .autocomplete({
        minLength: 4,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            if (request.term.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
                console.log(request.term);
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    jsonRisitas, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            }},
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( " " );
            return false;
        }
    }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        $('.suggestion').css({
            'height' : '80px'
        });
        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<div class='suggestion'><img width='50px' src='" + item.value + "'/>" +  item.label+"</div>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };

    /*.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li><div><img width='50px' src='"+item.value+"'><span>"+item.value+"</span></div></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };*/
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="message_topic"></textarea>
```

The words are as follows: pleure, rire, risitas and so on.

How can I make the suggestion display only when I type ": "+3 letters and not display all the time?

For example, I didn't put " : " and yet it still displays because there is " : " in the link of the image :/  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJlvz.png)
And another problem, I wanted to display only the images in the suggestion and not with tags, I already removed the tag names, it does not work :/ .

thank you in advance.
Steve